# Spring boot JMS Listener - org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.isAutoStartup()Z

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I have setup a JmsListener to read messages from a sqs queue.
Firtsly i created a configuration class like below to setup a ConnectionFactory and JMSTemplate

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableJms
 public class SQSJmsConfig {
 private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;

 @Value("${aws.ses.accessKey}")
 private String accessKey;

 @Value("${aws.ses.secretKey}")
 private String secretKey;

 @Bean
 public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);

    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),
            AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider));

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency("3-10");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);

    SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),
            AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider));

    return new JmsTemplate(sqsConnectionFactory);
 }
}
```

Then i created a JmsListener method to read messages from sqs queue

```
@Service
public class SQSQueueService {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSQueueService.class);

@JmsListener(destination = "${aws.sqs.queueName}")
public void readPlan(SQSEmailStatusQueue sqsEmailStatusQueue) {
    try {
        log.info("SNS notification received from SQS queue");
        String message = sqsEmailStatusQueue.getMessage();
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

After that when i run the project i got the following exception

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.isAutoStartup()Z

What is the reason for this exception ?

Comment: Please add your pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the dependency.

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`
```

I removed the version from this. Then it worked.
Can anybody please explain me why it happened ?

Answer (score 0):

The failure can occure if your application utilizes `spring-boot-starter-parent` and additionally depends on:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.jms.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Utilize this dependency provided by the parent instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```